# Removing "Stack Overflow" from titles and contents of the FAQs

Tags: discussion, title, meta-faq

#### Examples

- [How Does Stack Overflow Work? (The Official FAQ)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/how-does-stack-overflow-work-the-official-faq)
- [How does “Reputation” work on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow)
- [What are “Community Wiki” posts on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Since the FAQ is not specific to Stack Overflow (it's also used for Super User, Server Fault, and even somewhat for Meta) I propose to remove all specific references to SO from them, and substitute them either with nothing or "the website". For example:

- How does the website work? (The official FAQ)
- How does "Reputation" work?
- What are "Community Wiki" posts?

This would apply to their contents too:

> Some questions and answers in Stack Overflow are marked Community Wiki and are owned by a Community Wiki user.

would become:

> Some questions and answers are marked Community Wiki and are owned by a Community Wiki user.

I could just do it now, but I figured it would be a good idea to gather the community's consensus first, also meta-meta discussion is just cool.

Comment: That box at the top made me think this question was closed.

Comment: Many many many many captchas later.....

Comment: I didn't catch this question, so for a minute there I wasn't sure why you were editing all of those questions. It was also perhaps the best time to go through them, not many people are on now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where the question concerns the operation of *the software itself* (vs. some community standard like "are signatures allowed"), then this makes sense - as long as all four sites are running roughly the same software, this *should* work.

However, if you do get frisky and decide to start editing these, *please* try to come up with something better than "How does the website work?". As potentially misleading as "Stack Overflow" might be, at least it's gonna come up in searches for "stack overflow faq"...

Comment: How are the website work?

Comment: What about "How do Stack Overflow, Super User and Server Fault work?" Anyway I don't think it really matters because stackoverflow is in the domain name, so it will come up in searches regardless.