# What should the faq's title and scope be?

Tags: discussion, meta-faq

The title of the [FAQ "question"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/) here on meta used to be `Official Stack Overflow Community FAQ`. After the introduction of Server Fault and Super User I [changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40033/removing-stack-overflow-from-titles-and-contents-of-the-faqs) it to `The official FAQ for Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User`.

But now with Stack Exchange, meta-su and meta-sf everything changed again.

- What scope should the FAQ have? Should it be for all stack exchange websites, but with a section of stack overflow specific questions (like it is now)? Should it be split in two (one for stack exchange, one for SO)? Or what?
- What should its title be?

Answer (score 1):

I personally think splitting it in two would be a good idea. This would reflect what meta.stackoverflow.com is: the meta for all stack exchange websites, and also the meta for stack overflow.

I think for consistency reasons having a FAQ such as [What do the Stack Overflow colors mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-stackoverflow-colors-mean) in the stack exchange general FAQ wouldn't be ideal.

The titles could be:

- The official FAQ for Stack Exchange websites
- The official FAQ for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Just keep it as it is. Because this started as a programmer Q&A site, I would suggest that the new Stack Exchange sites can *override* the FAQ within their Meta-sites, if they need to.

Answer (score 0):

The official FAQ for all StackExchange member sites (and especially StackOverflow)